# how to execute a HttpPost request to my web server using google oauth2 access token

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient, google-oauth, access-token

I fetched google access token. Now I need to login to my web server by post to "mywebsite.com/login" with body as profile which we get by calling https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=. When I execute HttpPost request I'm supposed to get the response as json {key: "", userId:""} from my server. But its not working. My Log.i("JSON", json); is fetching the following error html page code. So could anyone help out with this. Is it the problem with my code? or something wrong with server? Thanks in advance.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("mywebsite.com/login"); 
 try {
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization","Bearer:"+"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key="+token));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));    
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(line + "\n");    }
    is.close();
    String json = sb.toString();
    Log.i("JSON", json);
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

ERROR (Log.i("JSON", json)) :-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/login">POST&nbsp;/login</a>    </em>.<p>
 Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at mywebsite.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```